# Can people please leave comments when they downvote questions and answers

Tags: discussion, voting, votes, down-votes

This is more of a request than a question, but if people down vote questions or answers could you please leave a comment in the appropriate place.

The point of the voting system is so good q/a can be easily spotted and bad q/a can be improved but if you don't tell people why you down voted them how can they improve it ?

Don't get me wrong down voting can be useful for helping manage bad questions but often times it is simply bad spelling or grammar that can simply be edited and then the votes can be changed.

As a guideline an effective procedure for down voting is as follows

First cast your down vote on the appropriate q or a,

Leave a small comment saying why you down voted (ie -1 the spelling is so bad I could not even read this )

Return later to see if the q/a has been edited, if it has, and meets your standards, then you can change your vote (returning any lost rep to you and the OP ) and remove your comment or edit it yourself to earn a little rep and help out the site.

This may seem like a small issue but it is an annoying and common problem I for one would like to see gone, it just seems like a common courtesy to me but I understand new users may simply not know how voting works so I write this to try combat this issue.

Comment: We have this kind of request here soooo often... I agree with you, but it won't change. And most users won't come back later to check their downvotes, as there is no good notification system for this, e.g. if the question got edited. And as far as I can tell, there will be no improvements in near future.

Comment: @ByteCommander That is a shame, I feel it is something that should be addressed, for many reasons ,but its not upto me, so will just have to live with it.

Comment: Yup, just live with it...  I always comment when downvoting, but I'm one of the exceptions.  And if an answer gets you 5*more downvotes then upvotes, it's time to delete it!  **;-)**

Comment: +1 A gentle reminder every so often isn't a bad thing.

Comment: Mostly I feel the ones that need downvoting won't listen to reason.

Comment: You are assuming that everyone is open to feedback. I leave comments often, but at times leaving feedback just starts a debate. My general sense when leaving feedback is - often it is ignored (lack of a notification system?), second most common response is to debate, and perhaps 5-10 % of the time there is some sort of a change and reversal of my downote.

Comment: What are you talking about? I always have *dozens* of constructive comments addressing what I did wrong!

Comment: Look at Oli's suggestion in the dupe, I think it would be the perfect solution.